# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape Google top feedback results for phone number

Tags: python, google-maps, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm a beginner at python. I trying to run a script that allows a person to input a university name to get a phone number back. The feedback google  result is all i need. for example of search `"university of alabama"`  then the word `"phone"`

but the result of running the code
brings me the result `"None"`

I need help getting down to the phone number in my scrape using beautiful soup.

Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]ng

Comment: Post a sample code not a picture of it, please.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `find` method wrong. You need to give the name of the tag and then any attribute that you can use to identify the specific tag uniquely. You can use the inspect tool find the tag in which the phone number is present.

[image]

Also, you may need to find your `user-agent` and pass it as a header to request to get the exact same response from google. Just search *"what is my user agent"* in google to find your user agent.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers={
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}
r=requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=university+of+alabama+phone',headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
ph_no=soup.find('div',class_='Z0LcW').text
print(ph_no)
```

Output

```
+1 205-348-6010
```

*Documentation*

[find() method - BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

Answer (score 0):

No guarantee this holds across all but you can use a css class selector to retrieve first result with select_one, wrapped in a try except

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = input("What would you like to search: ")
query = query.replace(" ","+")
query = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query + "phone"

r = requests.get(query)
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
try:
    s = soup.select_one(".mrH1y").text
except:
    s = "not found"
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

`CSS` selectors provided in answers by [QHarr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156436/15164646) and [Bitto Bennichan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156356/15164646) do not exist in the current Google Organic Results in HTML layout and it will throw an error (*if using without `try/except` block*).

Currently, it's this:

```py
>>> phone = soup.select_one('.mw31Ze').text
"+1 205-348-6010"
```

Also, it was returning `None` to you because there's no [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) specified thus Google blocked your request and you received a different HTML with some sort of error.

Because the default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814). Google understands it and blocks a request since it's not the "real" user visit. [Checks what's your `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Pass `user-agent` intro [request headers](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls):

```py
headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

requests.get("YOUR_URL", headers=headers)
```

---

Code:

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "hl": "en",
  "gl": "uk" # contry to search from. uk = United Kingdom. us = United States
}

query = input("What would you like to search: ")
query = f"https://www.google.com/search?q={query} phone"

response = requests.get(query, headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

try:
    phone = soup.select_one(".X0KC1c").text
except: phone = "not found"
print(phone)

'''
What would you like to search: university of alabama
+1 205-348-6010
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Knowledge Graph API](https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want rather than figuring out why certain things break and don't work as they should, and you don't have to maintain the parser over time if some selectors will be changed and cause the parser to brake.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "university of alabama phone",
  "gl": "uk",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

phone = results['knowledge_graph']['phone']
print(phone)

# +1 205-348-6010
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.